# Can't install Guest Additions Ubuntu 14 in Vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

I am trying to install the Guest Additions in Ubuntu 14, but I always get an error when install Virtual box guest additions.  I have installed all the headers. Can anyone point we to what it could be the error?

The error:

```
-fshort-wchar -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -I/lib/modules    /3.16.0-30-generic/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxsf/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxsf/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxsf/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DIN_MODULE -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DRT_NO_EXPORT_SYMBOL -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(regops)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxsf)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_regops.o /tmp/vbox.0/regops.c
/tmp/vbox.0/regops.c:577:20: error: ‘generic_file_aio_read’ undeclared here (not in a function)
     .aio_read    = generic_file_aio_read,
                    ^
/tmp/vbox.0/regops.c:578:20: error: ‘generic_file_aio_write’ undeclared here (not in a function)
     .aio_write   = generic_file_aio_write,
                    ^
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/regops.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/regops.o] Error 1
Makefile:1345: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/vbox.0' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.footer:79: recipe for target 'vboxsf' failed
make: *** [vboxsf] Error 2
Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.
```

My vagrant file:

```
~/vagrant/hadoop-mr-bft-coc-all$ cat Vagrantfile

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
  # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
  # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

  # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
  # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
  config.vm.box_url = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/utopic/current/utopic-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"


  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"
  config.vm.synced_folder "/home/xeon/vagrant/shared-folder", "/vagrant"

  # VBGuest: set auto_update to false, if you do NOT want to check the correct
  # additions version when booting this machine
  config.vbguest.auto_update = true

  # do NOT download the iso file from a webserver
  config.vbguest.no_remote = false

  # SSH attributes
  config.vm.define :node1 do |hadoop1|
    hadoop1.vm.box = "ubuntu"
    hadoop1.vm.hostname = "hadoop-coc-1"
    hadoop1.vm.network :private_network, :ip => '192.168.56.100'
    hadoop1.vm.provision :hosts
    # hadoop1.vm.synced_folder "/home/xeon/vagrant/shared-folder", "/vagrant"
    # hadoop1.vm.network "public_network"
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
        vb.gui = true
    end
  end

  config.vm.define :node2 do |hadoop2|
    hadoop2.vm.box = "node2"
    hadoop2.vm.hostname = "hadoop-coc-2"
    hadoop2.vm.network :private_network, :ip => '192.168.56.101'
    hadoop2.vm.provision :hosts
    # hadoop2.vm.network "public_network"
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
        vb.gui = true
    end
    # node2.vm.synced_folder "/home/xeon/vagrant/shared-folder", "/vagrant"
  end
end
```